# Store a sympy.core.mul.Mul variable into a binary file?

Tags: python, sympy, sage

I have a file including symbolic expressions using SymPy (SageMath), however when I try to save it to a file (as a string) the computer freezes.

```
str(K)
```

Thus, I think saving it as binary is the only option.

```
file = open('Full Stiffness.txt', 'wb') 
%time pickle.dump(K, file, -1)
file.close()
```

However, after saving it, the bytes saved are not as the original.
Thus, I think I should convert it to a format that can be saved in binary.

Note that `K` is a matrix (multidimensional array) whose entries are

```
<class 'sympy.core.mul.Mul'>
```

Comment: "when I try to save it" - how exactly are you saving it? What's the code? What do you mean by "the byte saved are not what I have in original"? Did you inspect the memory to compare the byte representation of Python objects to what was saved in the file?

Comment: What about using [pickle in SageMath](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/misc/sage/misc/persist.html)? Alternatively you could do the following in Python: 
```python
with open('filename.pickle', 'wb') as handle: 
    pickle.dump(sympy_expr, handle)
with sympy.evaluate(False): 
    with open('filename.pickle', 'rb') as handle: 
        result = pickle.load(handle)
```

Comment: @Maelstrom thanks, I tried with pickle but perhaps in the wrong way.

Comment: Have you tried using `srepr` instead of `str`?

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Thanks. I tried it but it get stuck like the other I think because expressions in each array component is extremely long so the only way to store it is using binary expressions into a file.